# Scrollable part of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, scroll

I want to have a similar effect like on this page: https://melaniedaveid.com/ (half of the page is scrollable).

I can make a sticky box, but there are certain things that I don't know how to make, such as the text. The text must be bigger than the box, but if `overflow: hidden`, then it is not scrollable. If it's `overflow: scroll`, it scrolls only if the mouse is hovering over the section, but I want the mouse to be able to scroll anywhere on the page.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.example {
  width: 50%;
}
 
.block {
  background: #888888;
  height: 300px;
/*   margin: 1em; */
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.block.one {
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
}

.orange{
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="block one"></div>
  <div class="block">
    <p class="box sticky"> </p>
  </div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="example">
  <div class="block one"></div>
  <div class="block orange"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Link for your example so we can work on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](https://codepen.io/raibove/pen/zYNJxgp) how you want it?

To create the sticky effect use `position: sticky`.

Code:

```css
#wrapper {
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction:row;
}


#sticky {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  background: #f83d23;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
  color: #fff;
}
#para{
  width:50%;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sticky">
    sticky
  </div>
  <div id="para">
    This is a para
   </div>
</div>
```